# Isn't IValueConverter just an example of "Conversions with helper classes"

Tags: c#

A coworker and myself where discussing conversion in .NET he pointed out there are four ways to convert a type, at first I could only come up with two, implicit and explicit then he pointed out user defined conversions and using helper classes so I decided to look it up here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx while reading that it dawned on me that I do a lot of WPF and often times use the IValueConverter interface.

My Question started as - isn't IValueConverter just an example of a conversion with a helper class (when you implement it of course)? Then I was like well, what is the real difference between user-defined conversions and conversions with a helper class? If you follow the links from the above mentioned MSDN page the documentation is sorda slim. Like this is the example from the conversion operators page.

```
class SampleClass
{
    public static explicit operator SampleClass(int i)
    {
        SampleClass temp = new SampleClass();
        // code to convert from int to SampleClass...

        return temp;
    }
}
```

It doesn't really make it so clear. To me it looks like a static class that needs an int in the ctor?

Anyway - Hopefully some C# ninja can illuminate this subject. One final thought is, I generally try and stay away from converting things unless there is a real good reason (i.e. parsing a spreadsheet) in regular everyday code I tend to think of it as a code smell, is that considered best practice?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a full answer to your questions, but that code snippet overrides the "explicit *cast*" of the class, which isn't really intuitive fromt eh method signature.  Basically it would allow you to do:

```
int one = 1;
SampleClass x = (SampleClass)one;
```

Common sense says that cast should fail, because and `int` isn't a `SampleClass` but the code snippet in your question comes into play, and makes the cast possible.

The other complementing method is:

```
public static implicit operator SampleClass(int i)
```

Note the keyword here is `implicit` instead of `explicit`, and this version would allow for implicit casting, so this would work:

```
int one = 1;
SampleClass x = one;
```

Note that you no longer have to specify the cast.